# Why is material reflecting what appears to be black on some objects?

Tags: texturing, materials

can anyone tell me why in the world these tube shapes are appearing this way? It's as if they're reflecting in different directions.. they almost appear black in some cases. It's a simple shader setup, only using principled BSDF, no tricks..[image]

Comment: hello, hard to say, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: it could be shadows

Comment: That looks more like flipped normals, or bad shading

Comment: Turns out this was an issue with Normals, solved by 'splitting' the normals, i.e. in edit mode: Mesh -> Normals -> Split. I'm not entirely sure what this does but it certainly solved the problem. Note: the object in the image is part of an imported OBJ file, it seems this isn't an uncommon issue with normals and OBJ imports. Hope this helps someone else in the future, and thanks for the input all.